# "don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up" even when they're all locked

Tags: bug, voting, notification-bar, locked

When I visit a site I haven't visited (while logged in) for a while, I see:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

That's often intended behavior. But today I visited [What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows) and was shown that banner even though the question and all its answers are locked. Voting arrows aren't even shown on any of the posts on that page.

I believe that banner should be disabled on pages where there is no post that can be voted on by anyone.

Comment: Also I feel that those close and locked notices are redundant. They both say they are not accepting new answers so I feel they could be merged somehow.

Comment: I feel like the notices are useless and get in the way anyway. I'd rather have them removed completely.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and came here to post the same bug report. +1.